# How to send a post request to google safebrowsing API v4 using the XHR(XmlHttpRequest)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, safe-browsing

I'm using XHR in my chrome extension to request google safe browsing api.Is there any XHR code available for google's safe brwosing api v4?

Comment: if asking for sample code, its offtopic. show attempts and issues.

Comment: @ZigMandel thx for ur answer, am already solve it.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).